# Updating Table with Joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

In my scenario I have two temp tables:

**Table1**:

```
  id | UserName | CalendarDate
 ----+----------+--------------
   1 | Null     | 2016-09-07 
   2 | Null     | 2016-09-07
```

**Table2**:

```
id | Emp_Name  | Date
---+-----------+-------------
 1 | Max       | 2016-09-07
 2 | Jupiter   | 2016-09-07
```

Here is my query which I am using to join two tables.

```
update #TABLE1 
set UserName = e.Emp_Name 
from #TABLE2 e 
join #TABLE l on e.Date = l.CalendarDate
```

After running the query it is updating `#Table1` rows with same `Emp_Name` in all the rows like this

```
id | UserName | CalendarDate
---+----------+----------------
 1 | Jupiter  | 2016-09-07
 2 | Jupiter  | 2016-09-07
```

I want my output to be like this

Table1

```
id | UserName | CalendarDate
---+----------+----------------
 1 | Max      | 2016-09-07
 2 | Jupiter  | 2016-09-07
```

Please if anyone can help me on this it will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Since your `#Table1` has the **same date** for both rows, the update statement will first update both rows to `Max`, and then both rows to `Jupiter`..... what you need is a **proper PRIMARY KEY** on those tables so you don't have to rely on a column like `Date` which obviously isn't unique for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a little bit your UPDATE statement:

```
update l --Instead of #TABLE1
set UserName = e.Emp_Name 
from #TABLE2 e 
join #TABLE1 l 
    on e.id= l.id -- use ID instead of dates
```

Comment: Thanks gofr1 but this query is also not working it is showing same result

Comment: I get it, you are joining on dates and they could be the same for names, you should use ID

Comment: Fixed answer, please, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks gofr1 i changed it to id. now it is working perfectly. Thanks again